# I can't boot into bootloader on Sony Xperia S (unlocked and rooted)

Tags: android, linux, bootloader, sony, ubuntu-touch

I'm looking to flash another operating system (Ubuntu-touch) onto my xperia S. But in order to do that I need to be in the bootloader. I have already unlocked the bootloader (as evidenced by the *#*#7378423#*#* menu). I have also rooted my phone, as I thought that might be the fix.

When I reboot my phone into the bootloader (from linux pc using '$ adb reboot-bootloader'), the notification LED lights up in blue, but the screen stays black/off.

Does anyone know what is wrong or what I have to do in order to get the bootloader working?

Thanks in advance for your help! I hope someone has the answer.

Thanks, DevNoob

Comment: When it is in this state (led on, screen off) and you type `fastboot devices` - Does it recognize your device?

Comment: Yes it does recognize my device as being in fastboot.

Comment: so you can basically do whatever you want. The "Bootloader" is usually just a screen, you don't need that in order to complete your instructions.
to flash a recovery just use `fastboot flash recovery myRecovery.img` or if you have an image of the system on your computer use `fastboot flash system systemImage.img`.
It should work because you're recognized as fastboot device.
I don't know why you don't see anything, but as far as I know, you could work nonetheless.

Comment: Oke, I just tried to flash ubuntu onto the device (by using the command in the ubuntu manual: ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap)

So now it says the following:
2014/05/28 15:57:18 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting

Comment: try `ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap=false`

Comment: the terminal tells me the following: bool flag '--bootstrap' cannot have an argument

Comment: using ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel \\
the terminal says it is 'expecting the device to expose an adb interface' and then gives an 'exit status 255' message

Comment: According to the manual on http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ubuntu-device-flash.1.html it should work... The only possibility is that `ubuntu-device-flash` does only work for Nexus-devices, because the manpage states `provision supported Nexus devices with Ubuntu`. But I'm not entirely sure about that.

So I'm sorry, I can't help any further...

Comment: Ooh, now you mention it I did find something about sony flash commands being different, a couple of weeks ago.
thanks for the help! you have brought me a step closer.

Comment: Glad I could help. So I'll write it as answer and you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: ohw, you put the link to the device specific instructions in the answer. Great job!!

Comment: Hey ManuToMatic,

Do you know anything about flashing to the phone? Because I found the image to flash to the phone and I did. I flashed a boot.img file to the using: 'sudo fastboot flash boot boot.img' which the terminal tells me went OKAY. 

the problem is, I accidently (or stupidly) flashed the same boot.img to the system (by using: sudo fastboot flash system boot.img.

Comment: Lol, still getting used to having to use shift+enter here..

anyway, still wanted to say that I do have a system folder that I downloaded along with the boot.img.

Comment: You should have a system.img besides the boot.img. If so, you can simply in fastboot use 'fastboot flash system system.img'

Comment: yeah that's the problem, there is only a folder called system. but no system.img file. I'll check if I can find a system.img file online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Bootloader is working, it does only just not show any screen.

The issue with the flashing however is the command `ubuntu-device-flash`

According to its [Manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/ubuntu-device-flash.1.html) this command does only work with Google Nexus devices.

For Sony-devices you can download a port from [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices) and flash it.